# shrinkwrap or surface deform for clothing poking through other clothing?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, armature, shrinkwrap, surface-deform

i am looking specifically for a non-physics approach to rigging clothing. i have a rigged character with a shirt and jeans, weights are directly copied from the body via Transfer Weights. I have attempted to use both shrinkwrap (nearest surface point + snap mode: outside) and subsurface deform modifiers so that the shirt behaves "correctly", but the jeans / butt pokes out in both uses. i think this is a feature of both modifiers rather than a bug.
i have tried to use only the front of the shirt as a vertex group with some results, but this obviously means moving the leg backwards causes problems.

[image]

[image]

i think i'm looking for "conditional movement" and as a complete novice my guess is to use something with constraint like a shape key? i don't know.. i also do not think hiding the mesh underneath is appropriate here, i am going to move the camera a lot.

blend file: https://blend-exchange.com/b/dPKqdere

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like adding topology (horizontal edge loops) will fix the problem:

[image]

You could also create bones all around the bottom of your coat in order to precisely control it:

[image]

Comment: ahh it's so obvious LOL. I am considering making lower-polygon models in the future, is this the only way out as well? regardless, thank you!

Comment: You could also create bones all around the bottom of your coat in order to precisely control it